# Can I use Google Colab processing power for own website?

Tags: python, cloud, google-colaboratory, image-classification

I want to build a website for Image classification, detection and the other data tasks. The problem is, my laptop does not have enough power to run these task fast. Is there a way to redirect user input from website to Google Colab or other service (AWS, Microsoft), which has enough graphical resource, and return the result back to website?